# Accessing the nested Structural Elements

Tags: c, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct a
{
    float n;
    int e;
};

struct b
{
    struct a *c;
}h;

int main()
{
    h.c->n=4;
    printf("%f",h.c->n);
    return 0;
}
```

Yes it is small code but I have been trying to access the element e which is instruct a through the struct b. The code is compiled without any error but in the output screen, it is blank.

Please suggest me a good way to access the element in the struct a.

Please note that the struct a has been declared inside the struct b as a pointer.

Comment: Your code invokes *undefined behavior*. You never assign `h.c` to point to any valid memory region. Therefore `h.c->n` dereferences an *indeterminate* pointer, and in so doing, sends your program behavior into the abyss. This isn't a nesting problem; it's an undefined-behavior problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would crash because your pointer `c` was never allocated.

```
h.c->n=4;  // pointer `c` has not been pointing to anything valid
```

---

To make it work, you need something like this:

```
struct a aa;  // must allocate an item of struct `a` first
aa.n = 4;
aa.e = 0;

h.c = &aa;    // then make pointer `c` to point that that item
printf("%f",h.c->n);   // before trying to access that pointer
```